# Why doesn't std::unique_ptr implicitly convert to T* and const T*?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I were to write it myself, I guess I'd do something like:

```
template<typename T, typename Dtor = std::default_delete<T> >
class Uptr : private Dtor {
  T* vl_;
public:
  explicit Uptr(T* vl = nullptr) noexcept : vl_(vl) {}
  ~Uptr() noexcept { Dtor::operator()(vl_); }

  Uptr& swap(Uptr& o) noexcept { T* tmp; tmp = vl_; vl_=o.vl_; o.vl_ = tmp; }

  Uptr& operator=(Uptr&& o) noexcept { o.swap(*this); }
  Uptr& operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept { vl_=nullptr; return *this; } 
  Uptr(Uptr&& o) noexcept : Uptr(nullptr) { *this = std::move(o); } 

  Uptr(const Uptr& o) = delete;
  Uptr& operator=(const Uptr& o) = delete;


  operator T*() noexcept { return vl_; } 
  operator const T*() const noexcept { return vl_; } 

  T* release() noexcept { T* ret = vl_; vl_=nullptr; return ret; }    

  const Dtor& deleter() const noexcept { return *(static_cast<Dtor*>(this)); }
  Dtor& deleter() noexcept { return *(static_cast<Dtor*>(this)); }
};
```

And save myself from having to define `get()` and operators `*`, `->`, and `[]`.

What's wrong with having implicit conversions in this case?

Comment: Implicit conversions are just evil. If it can be implicitly converted to a pointer, it makes it much harder to reason about the ownership of that pointer because you can pass it to a method that's expecting to receive a bare pointer...

Comment: They're evil in many contexts but I'm not entirely convinced about this particular context. The absolute majority of functions that take pointers do not care how the lifetime of the pointer is managed. There are only a handful of functions that do care, and using those outside of ctors and dtors is a red flag by itself. The conversion in this case is kind of akin to public inheritance from the pointer (which would make sense (a unique pointer IS A pointer that also owns the object), but is technically impossible because pointers aren't class types).

Comment: `operator []` is defined.

Comment: Okay, sure, but what do you lose? You have to type a couple of extra characters because there's no implicit conversion, but now it's completely unambiguous what's going on. Is it really worth it? Type once, read many. Same logic for `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: @CodyGray Good point. Nothing really in this case. The slight inconvenience is just syntactical, and I've realized I can workaround that by creating wrappers with inheritance for both unique_ptr and shared_ptr. If it proves to cause problems, I can simply turn those wrapper names into type aliases. Thanks everyone for the input.

Comment: Completely sacrifice type safety and code clarity to save typing a few characters ... not a good trade off.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think your question is specific to `unique_ptr`, but rather asking about smart pointers in general.

[Herb Sutter wrote about this a long time ago](http://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/). Apparently, it would allow you to write logically-erroneous code such as:

```
unique_ptr<something> p;
...
delete p; // p is a smart pointer - probably not what you want.
```

and other code like that.

Comment: "the above could be solved by overloading delete and using a static assert" No, it can't.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for your comment. I'll try to figure out why. Will comment it out for now.

Answer (score 8):

There are some annoying errors that might happen, as others have pointed out, like

```
T* f() { unique_ptr p{...}; return p; } // oops

unique_ptr p{...}; delete p; // oops
```

and

```
unique_ptr get_up();

shared_ptr sp{get_up()}; // cool, this works: promote UP to SP

// does it work the other way around?

shared_ptr get_sp();

unique_ptr p{get_sp()}; // compiles, then yes! eh, wait.. BOOM!
```

And so on. It's just safer, considering that that language is designed for humans, to dodge these pitfalls by making everything explicit in such cases.

Answer (score 6):

I have no formal answer, but I have an idea why this would not make much sense. The whole idea of `unique_ptr` is to be a strongly typed (i.e. compiler-enforced) way to carry unique ownership of an object. Hence the move semantics.

In that context, it makes sense to have the `unique_ptr` require you to explicitly request its raw pointer, because as soon as you have the raw value, you can easily break everything: you could `delete` it, you could pass it to another smart pointer (which would in turn delete it at some point), or do pointer arithmetics and accidentally work with the result (which might not point to allocated memory) or anything like that. Some of this may immediately lead to compiler errors, others may lead to undefined behaviour. For a high-level class such as `unique_ptr`, this is not desirable, at least not this implicitly. Of course you can do the same using `.get()`, but in that case, you *know* that you are using the raw pointer value and that you must not free it.

The [link posted by Ami](http://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/) is also very relevant, but I think a different example is better quoted:

```
unique_ptr p( new widget );
...
use( p + 42 ); // error (maybe he meant "*p + 42"?)
    // but if implicit conversion to * were allowed, would silently compile -- urk
```

The C++ philosophy is that public *functions* which can operate on a given type belong to the interface of that type. Controlling and restricting the interface of a type which implicitly converts to a pointer is virtually impossible. The intentionally restrictive nature of smart pointers would be entirely deconstructed, leading to error prone code.